# Commute a sentence? To where?

Tags: meaning, etymology

A petition to pardon "Making a Murderer" subject Steven Avery made news recently when it was [responded to by the White House's We the People team.](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/pardon-steven-avery-and-brendan-dassey-their-alleged-involvement-murder-teresa-halbach)

I became interested by the response when I read about "**commutations**". Referring to President Obama's past activities...

> That's why he has granted 184 commutations total -- more than the last five presidents combined -- and has issued 66 pardons over his time in office.

*Commute* here seems to be different than pardoning. Perhaps it only means to lessen a sentence, versus *pardoning's* complete removal of one?

Anyway, the definition of commute that I believe is more common is like "to travel to or from work".

How are these two definitions related? What is their common interpretation?

Comment: When someone is "pardoned" then their "record" is wiped clean -- it's as if the crime never occurred.  If a sentence is "commuted" that means that the penalty (such as imprisonment) is eliminated, but the crime still remains on your "record".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb ***commute*** has seven main meanings with eight sub-meanings in the OED.

Essential to *commute* is the notion of exchanging one thing for another. (It comes from the Latin *commutare* meaning *to change altogether*.) Hence a death sentence can be ***commuted*** to a term of imprisonment.

The idea of *commuting to work* (meaning travelling over some distance) occupies meaning 4b. It is of US origin and derives from the term *commutation-ticket*, which in Britain we would call a *season-ticket*. The idea is that the purchase of many tickets is *exchanged* for the purchase of just one - the *commutation ticket*.

The definition and examples the OED gives of ***commutation-ticket*** are:

> commutation ticket  n. (U.S.) a ticket issued by a railway company,
>   etc., at a reduced rate, entitling the holder to travel over a given
>   route a certain number of times or during a certain period; a
>   season-ticket.
>
> 1848   Amer. Railroad Jrnl. 29 July 481/3   Commutation tickets..,
>   costing $5, are issued at Trenton, signed by ‘B. Fish’, which entitles
>   the receiver to eight passages between Trenton and New Brunswick, by
>   any line on the route.
>
> 1879   Constit. Calif. in J. Bryce Amer. Commonw. (1888) II. App. 671 
>   Excursion and commutation tickets issued at special rates.
>
> 1885   Good Words July 450/1   A single ‘Commutation’ ticket is given,
>   numbered and dated on the day on which it was issued.

Answer (score 1):

"Commutation - Legal Definition.
In criminal law, the president’s or governor’s substitution of a less severe punishment for a greater one that was imposed by a court in a criminal action. See also amnesty, pardon, and reprieve.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/commutation

"Webster's New World Law Dictionary Copyright © 2010 by Wiley Publishing, Inc., Hoboken, New Jersey. Used by arrangement with John Wiley & Sons, Inc.

Read more at http://www.yourdictionary.com/commutation#0ock6AJrDxdCyASq.99 "

Note that this site also includes the etymology of the word, answering your question with regards to the word "commute."